# Firebase: how to know which database a user has been logged

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

A web application has a screen where the user enters:
`projectId`, `username` and `password` to get details of the firebase database. The db has been set using email/password as signin method. And users email and passwords has been added. This is for multiple firebase projects. The interface is common for all.

After a user has successfully logged in by providing the 3 parameters. I noticed that a firebaseLocalstorageDb is created. What does it store and is there a way to access it?

Also, is there a way to know the currently logged user. I cannot use the `firebase.auth().currentUser` or the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` since I do not know which firebase the user has logged into (unless I store that in local storage, which I am currently doing).

I set the firebase app by using the project id specified by the user in the input screen and retrieve *that* project's configuration. And later when the user re-visits the website, I would like to set the firebase app by determining the project id that was used to successfully login.

I was wondering if the `firebaseLocalstorageDb` has the answer. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not know which firebase the user has logged into"?  That's something you are in control of.

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth.currentUser.uid`
  `firebase.auth.currentUser.email`
Try this

Comment: firebase.auth requires setting of the app using the db config. But in my case, I do not know which db the user has logged in to

Answer (score 0):

> What does it store and is there a way to access it?

Firebase Authentication uses local storage is used to keep the user's authentication token. Based on that Firebase Authentication can restore the user's authentication state when the page is reloaded.

To get the result of the authentication state, [use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

If you want to know the project the user has signed in to, that will be the same project you configured. So you can use the same data from the [Firebase configuration object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object) that you pass into `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`. Alternatively, you can look it up from `firebase.app().options.projectId` (if you're using the default app name).

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen for the response. But how do I know the firebaseConfig, (required to initialize the app) unless I know which project-id the user has successfully logged in in the previous session? when the user initially logs in, I programmatically get that project's  firebase db config from the back end using project-id and then submit the signinWithEmailAndPassword function

Comment: Did you try printing `firebase.app().options.projectId`? If that's not it, you may be something that I don't immediately understand. In that case (well actually, in any case) it would really help to see the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let me check and revert. If not will set up a mcve. Thanks

Comment: when I look at the api, `firebase.app()` would return the default app but in my case there is no default app since I do not know which firebase db to use. That is why currently, I am storing the project id and the config details in localstorage and when the user visits the website, it uses that config to set the app. My question was: can I do it without storing in localstorage using the indexDb. Perhaps not